# How can I edit the read.me file on github?

Tags: github

How can I edit the read.me file on github?

Answer (score 4):

You can edit the *Readme.md* file just the way you would edit any other file on your repository. There are two options:

1. **Editing from your local machine:** simply pull the repository to prevent any potential conflict (e.g. `git pull origin main`) and then open the *Readme.md* file in your desired text editor and make the necessary changes (if there is no such file, you could create one). Save the file and then update your Github repository (`git commit -am "Readme.md updated"` and then `git push`).
2. **Editing directly on Github:** Github website offers you its built-in editor to make the necessary changes online. Open up your browser, log into your Github account, navigate to the desired repository and click on the *Readme.md* file (or basically any file). Click on the pencil icon on the top-right of the file-viewer and you could edit the file in your browser.

[image: Edit this file]

Pro tip: You could use Markdown to stylize your *Readme.md* file. Check out this [Markdown Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)!

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the main page of the repository, there is button on the top right bar of README's beginning. Click on it and then you can edit and save your changes.

[image]